# Why does console.log work but not return?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on this Kata:
Write a function that takes in a string of one or more words, and returns the same string, but with all five or more letter words reversed (Just like the name of this Kata). Strings passed in will consist of only letters and spaces. Spaces will be included only when more than one word is present.

This isn't the most beautiful code but how come console.log prints the expected result and the return commands (which I've commented out) do not work?

```
function spinWords(sentence){

  function reverse(s) {
    return s.split('').reverse().join('');
  }

  var words = sentence.split(" ");

  for (var i=0; i<words.length; i++){
    var word = words[i].toString();
    var backwards = reverse(word);

    if (word.length>=5){
      console.log(backwards);
      //return backwards;
    } else {
      console.log(word);
      //return word;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What do you expect it to do, and what does it actually (not) do?

Comment: I'd guess it has something to do with how you're using the returned value. You haven't shown us that code.

Comment: If you uncomment the `return` statements, then you're always going to return on the first iteration of the `for` loop. Once you return, the function terminates, so the loop can't continue.

Answer (score 3):

I guess your main issue is that you're trying to return within a for loop which will not give you all the words that you're passing in, basically your if else statement will return on the first itteration.

Assuming you're expecting to see the full result of the `sentance` variable you're injecting:

```
function spinWords(sentence){

    function reverse(s) {
        return s.split('').reverse().join('');
    }

    var words = sentence.split(" ");
    var strings = [];
    for (var i=0; i<words.length; i++) {
        var word = words[i].toString();
        var backwards = reverse(word);

        if (word.length>=5){
            strings.push(backwards);
            console.log(backwards);
            //return backwards;
        } else {
            strings.push(word);
            console.log(word);
            //return word;
        }
    }

    return strings.join(' ');
}
```

Using:

`var sentance = spinWords('foood is great!')`

Result of `console.log(sentance)`:

`"dooof is !taerg"`

Comment: Thank you! That helps clear up some of my confusion re: console.log versus return.

Comment: Would you mind accepting the answer by clicking the tick above if it has helped :)